# Copying certain cells from a row, when criterea are met, and pasting into a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy cells A:D from a row, when column E = "Accepted", and paste the data, as values, into a different sheet.

Every time I try though, it only copies the last row and I can't understand why. I'd be really grateful for any help.

My code looks like this:

```
Public Sub AcceptLastChangeRequest()

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
End With

On Error GoTo errorHandler:

    Dim varAnswer As String
        varAnswer = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to accept the most recent Change Request?", vbYesNo, "Accept Change Request")
            If varAnswer = vbNo Then
                MsgBox ("No changes saved")
                    With Application
                        .ScreenUpdating = True
                        .EnableEvents = True
                    End With
                Exit Sub
            End If

    Dim SourceRange As Range, DestRange As Range
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowDestSheet As Long, i As Long, LastRowSourceSheet As Long
        Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Accepted Change Requests")
        Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Change Requests")

            LastRowDestSheet = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            LastRowSourceSheet = SourceSheet.Cells(SourceSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To LastRowSourceSheet
                    If Sheets("All Change Requests").Range("E" & i).Value = "Accepted" Then
                        Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.Range("A" & i, "D" & i)
                        Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("A" & LastRowDestSheet + 1)
                        SourceRange.Copy
                        DestRange.PasteSpecial _
                        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                        skipblanks:=False, _
                        Transpose:=False

                        Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    End If
                Next i

            With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            End With

    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
MsgBox ("There was an error adding this Change Request")
Resume Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Another approach, possibly faster, would be to use the .AutoFilter selecting "accepted" for column E.  Then copy/paste the Visible cells (in columns A:D) in a single bloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the last row of the destination sheet.

Put

```
LastRowDestSheet = LastRowDestSheet + 1
```

in the end of the if-clause (after 'Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range...')

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your loop with this:

```
For i = 2 To LastRowSourceSheet
   If SourceSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = "Accepted" Then _
     DestSheet.Range("A" & LastRowDestSheet + 1 & ":D" & LastRowDestSheet + 1).Value = _
         SourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value   
   LastRowDestSheet = LastRowDestSheet + 1
Next i
```

---

**EDIT** *(Further OP request)*

```
For i = 2 To LastRowSourceSheet
   If SourceSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = "Accepted" Then
     If Evaluate("ISERROR(MATCH(A" & i & ",'Accepted Change Requests'!A:A,0))") Then 
         DestSheet.Range("A" & LastRowDestSheet + 1 & ":D" & LastRowDestSheet + 1).Value = _
            SourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
         LastRowDestSheet = LastRowDestSheet + 1
     End If
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: That's fantastic and does exactly what I asked. but is there any way to only paste the data into the "Accepted Change Requests" if the data in column A of the copied data does not already exist in column A of the destination sheet (i.e. there isn't already a chnage request with that unique ID).

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to clarify a bit more, `DestSheet` _is_ the "Accepted Change Requests" sheet so the values are only copied there?

Comment: Basically any new change requests will be added to "All Change Requests" sheet and will be assigned a unique ID in column A. I only want to copy those which are accepted, by setting the value of column E to "Accepted", onto the "Accepted Change Requests" sheet. However, I do not want any change requests that already appear on the "Accepted Change Requests" to be duplicated. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: You'd have to add a unique ID for that purpose. Also copy that unique ID to the dest sheet and iterate over existing entries/autofilter them to check for the unique ID you are copying at the moment

Comment: EngJohn - How would I do that?

Comment: Thanks but that only copies across the first accepted change request

Comment: Did you remove the data from 'Accepted' sheet first? This checks to see if the ID in Columns A already exists in column A of the 'Accepted' sheet, if it does, skip the copy, if it doesn't, copy the data...

Comment: I removed all data, apart from my headings, from the accepted sheet before running the macro. It still only copies the first accepted entry.

Comment: I've made a small further edit which implicitly tells the evaluation to look for an _exact_ match, you can see if that has any difference. Other than that it's bit hard without actually seeing the data.

Comment: I'm also trying to get the code to insert the date at which the change request is first carried over onto the destination sheet into column e of the destination sheet but when I do this it doesn't add it to the correct row. I just added the following code to the loop `code`With DestSheet.Range("E" & i)
                                    .Value = Date
                                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" `code`

Comment: Don't worry, stupid mistake. I solved it by changing the addittion to the loop to: `code`                                 With DestSheet.Range("E" & LastRowDestSheet + 1)
                                    .Value = Date
                                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" `code`